# How to add() runtime input in a set in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

**Problem**

I am trying to `add()` elements in a set at run time using a for loop:

```
    l1=set(map(int, input().split()))
    n=int(input())
    l2=set()
    for i in range(n):
        l2.add([int, input().split()])
    print(l1)
    print(l2)
```

Surprisingly, `l1` is a set but, when I go on `add()` -ing elements to my set `l2` in a loop I get :

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

**Research Effort:**

Here are other ways I have tried to `add()` elements to set `l2` and failed :

```
l2=set()
for i in range(n):
    l2.add(map(int, input().split()))
```

The above prints out :

```
{<map object at 0x000001D5E88F36A0>, <map object at 0x000001D5E8C74AC8>}
```

Even this does not work!!

```
for i in range(n):
    l2.add(set(map(int, input().split())))
```

Please feel free to point out what I am doing wrong.

> Basically, an answer will be helpful if one can *explain how to add
>   elements to a set data structure at runtime in a loop*

**Clarification:**

I am looking for making a set of sets with user inputs at run time:

So if the user gives the following input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 23 45 84 78
2
1 2 3 4 5
100 11 12
```

The first line is my set `l1`. The second line is the number of sets and so since it is 2, the line afterwards are contents of the set.

*Expected output:*

```
{{1,2,3,4,5},{100,11,12}}
```

Comment: Try `(int, tuple(input.split()))`. Mutable objects don't have hashcodes (since they would change when mutated and it would break how hash collections work). `set` is implemented using a hashtable so it can store only immutable stuff (or at least: stuff whose identity is immutable). `list`s are mutable hence don't have a hashcode. `split` also returns a list.

Comment: Sure, let me check and revert back.

Comment: I get : AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Sorry `input().split()` the missing parenthesis were a typo

Comment: I wrote l2.add((int, tuple( input.split())))

Comment: I tried the other version and i get - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Your expected output is not possible. ``set`` is not a valid type for ``set`` members.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I understand, Mad Physicst has suggested an approach using frozenset() which seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since l am now answering an essentially different question, I am posting a second answer.

A [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) is mutable, and therefore unhashable. Mutable objects can implement a hash function, but the built-in ones generally don't to avoid issues. Instead of using a `set`, use a hashable [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) for your nested sets:

```
l2 = set()
for i in range(n):
    l2.add(frozenset(map(int, input().split())))
```

OR

```
l2 = {frozenset(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)}
```

OR

```
l2 = set(frozenset(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n))
```

You won't be able to modify the sub-sets of `l2`, but they will behave as sets for at other purposes.

Comment: I'm trying it out. Will let you know in a sec

Comment: I'm not much familiar with frozenset() but my output shows as - {frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), frozenset({11, 100, 12})}

Comment: It looks like each element is different to other and is a set.But not sure why the word frozenset written in them

Comment: @mishsx. Because when you print a built-in container, it prints the elements with `repr`. The `repr` of a `frozenset` is a string that should let you construct the object, and so contains the word `frozenset`.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`set.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add) only accepts as single element, not an iterable, you can loop over the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and add each element individually

```
l2 = set()
for i in range(n):
    for element in map(int, input().split()):
    l2.add(element)
```

This is not, in my opinion, as elegant as turning the `map` into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) as you did with `l1`, and adding it to the existing set:

```
l2 = set()
for i in range(n):
    l2 |= set(map(int, input().split()))
```

You can use [`set.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) to avoid having to convert the `map` to a `set` explicitly:

```
l2 = set()
for i in range(n):
    l2.update(map(int, input().split()))
```

In fact, `update` can accept any number of iterables, so you can (but probably shouldn't) write a one-liner for the update:

```
l2 = set()
l2.update(*[map(int, input().split()) for i in range(n)])
```

Comment: Your approach works well. But what I was looking for was perhaps if I could make it as a set of sets.

Comment: Like append n sets with runtime inputs in l2. { {....} , {...}, {....},....{...}}

Comment: I tried your edits and I am still not able to see it as a set of sets. Please feel free to address your confusions I am willing to help you with that.

Comment: @mishx. Show expected output in every part of the question.

Comment: I have added the expected output

Comment: @mishsx. That helps more than the prose. I've gone ahead and added a second distinct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hopeful this helps you.

```
l1=set(map(int, input('Enter first set: ').split()))
print(l1)
n=int(input('Enter n: '))
l2=set()
for i in range(n):
    l2 = l2 | set(map(int, input(f'Enter {i+2}rd set: ').split()))

print(l2)
# {1,2,3,4,5,100,11,12}
```

- In python you cannot have set of lists
- Use merge operator instead of add
- The `{{1,2,3,4,5},{100,11,12}}` expression is both mathematically and programming wrong.
- Mathematically set of sets is intersection of sets.
- You can have list of sets but no sets of sets. So `l2` should be list not set.here is the code to make list of sets.

  ```
  l1 = set(map(int, input('Enter first set: ').split()))
  print(l1)
  n = int(input('Enter n: '))
  l2 = list()
  for i in range(n):
      l2.append(set(set(map(int, input(f'Enter {i + 2}rd set: ').split()))))

  print(l2)

  # [{1,2,3,4,5},{100,11,12}]
  ```

Comment: I'll try that out now and let you know

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but it gives me a set with consolidated elements of the sets i give in input. I have attached a clarification on my post. Please feel free to address any doubts you still have.

Comment: Blue You're correct about the part where illogical and mathematically wrong to make a set of sets. But with frozenset() I was able to. I appreciate your elegant solution and will refer the same, since I will always run into a case to make a list of sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
inn = input("enter the number of elements in set")
set1 = set()
for i in range(int(inn)):
    print (i)
    in1 = input("enterset elements:")
    set1.add(in1)
print (set1)
```

Comment: Hope this is very simple set to construct in runtime